# Setting image path in sql developer to get the image in c# application

Tags: c#, sql, image, oracle, ado.net

I am currently working on a project for school and I have to store image paths in our database in sqldeveloper and then use this path to show the image in our c# application. What I'm currently having problem with is knowing what path to write in the databse so the application can get them from any computers. I have all my images in a document in my project called /Images, but is the path that I have to enter in the DB? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can give your image a unique identifier. So when you save an image in your /Images folder it will have a name like 5a864a4e-23d8-4c08-867a-16e52a4b94be.jpg. Then from your application you could access the image from /Images/5a864a4e-23d8-4c08-867a-16e52a4b94be.jpg. You can give a little more details if you need something more specific. Hope it helps.